# System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String] in the badge list page

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, tag-badges

In the [badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges) page (in every SE site), under Tag badges there's some code: `` System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String] ``:

> [image]

Credit goes to [rtx13](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396158) and [mightyteja](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/396038/revisions) (edited out because it was off-topic) and posted it on MSO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will be fixed shortly, we missed an `await` call in our .NET Core port.

Comment: .NET Core ≈ No Windows Updates to deal with?